# Numpy Histogram - Python

Tags: python, class, numpy, histogram

I have a problem in which a have a bunch of images for which I have to generate histograms. But I have to generate an histogram for each pixel. I.e, for a collection of n images, I have to count the values that the pixel 0,0 assumed and generate an histogram, the same for 0,1, 0,2 and so on. I coded the following method to do this:

```
class ImageData:
    def generate_pixel_histogram(self, images, bins):
    """
    Generate a histogram of the image for each pixel, counting
    the values assumed for each pixel in a specified bins
    """
        max_value = 0.0
        min_value = 0.0
        for i in range(len(images)):
            image = images[i]
            max_entry = max(max(p[1:]) for p in image.data)
            min_entry = min(min(p[1:]) for p in image.data)
            if max_entry > max_value:
                max_value = max_entry
            if min_entry < min_value:
                min_value = min_entry

        interval_size = (math.fabs(min_value) + math.fabs(max_value))/bins

        for x in range(self.width):
            for y in range(self.height):
                pixel_histogram = {}
                for i in range(bins+1):
                    key = round(min_value+(i*interval_size), 2)
                    pixel_histogram[key] = 0.0
                for i in range(len(images)):
                    image = images[i]
                    value = round(Utils.get_bin(image.data[x][y], interval_size), 2)
                    pixel_histogram[value] += 1.0/len(images)
                self.data[x][y] = pixel_histogram
```

Where each position of a matrix store a dictionary representing an histogram. But, how I do this for each pixel, and this calculus take a considerable time, this seems to me to be a good problem to be parallelized. But I don't have experience with this and I don't know how to do this.

EDIT:

I tried what @Eelco Hoogendoorn told me and it works perfectly. But applying it to my code, where the data are a large number of images generated with this constructor (after the values are calculated and not just 0 anymore), I just got as h an array of zeros [0 0 0]. What I pass to the histogram method is an array of ImageData.

```
class ImageData(object):

    def __init__(self, width=5, height=5, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        """
        The ImageData constructor
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #The values range each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        self.data = np.arange(width*height).reshape(height, width)

#Another class, just the method here
def generate_pixel_histogram(realizations, bins):
    """
    Generate a histogram of the image for each pixel, counting
    the values assumed for each pixel in a specified bins
    """
    data = np.array([image.data for image in realizations])
    min_max_range = data.min(), data.max()+1

    bin_boundaries = np.empty(bins+1)

    # Function to wrap np.histogram, passing on only the first return value
    def hist(pixel):
        h, b = np.histogram(pixel, bins=bins, range=min_max_range)
        bin_boundaries[:] = b
        return h

    # Apply this for each pixel
    hist_data = np.apply_along_axis(hist, 0, data)
    print hist_data
    print bin_boundaries
```

Now I get:

```
  hist_data = np.apply_along_axis(hist, 0, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 104, in apply_along_axis
  outshape[axis] = len(res)
  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by john, the most obvious solution to this is to look for library functionality that will do this for you. It exists, and it will be orders of magnitude more efficient than what you are doing here.

Standard numpy has a histogram function that can be used for this purpose. If you have only few values per pixel, it will be relatively inefficient; and it creates a dense histogram vector rather than the sparse one you produce here. Still, chances are good the code below solves your problem efficiently.

```
import numpy as np
#some example data; 128 images of 4x4 pixels
voxeldata = np.random.randint(0,100, (128, 4,4))
#we need to apply the same binning range to each pixel to get sensibble output
globalminmax = voxeldata.min(), voxeldata.max()+1
#number of output bins
bins = 20
bin_boundaries = np.empty(bins+1)
#function to wrap np.histogram, passing on only the first return value
def hist(pixel):
    h, b = np.histogram(pixel, bins=bins, range=globalminmax)
    bin_boundaries[:] = b  #simply overwrite; result should be identical each time
    return h
#apply this for each pixel
histdata = np.apply_along_axis(hist, 0, voxeldata)
print bin_boundaries
print histdata[:,0,0]  #print the histogram of an arbitrary pixel
```

But the more general message id like to convey, looking at your code sample and the type of problem you are working on: do yourself a favor, and learn numpy.

Comment: Thank you. I've already used histogram from `Matplotlib`, but I really didn't know how to apply the `numpy` `histogram` (however I knew that it exist) for multiple images / pixel (and don't think that it is something trivial), and not just the entire image. I just don't get in your code how `hist = lambda pixel: np.histogram(pixel, bins=bins, range=globalminmax)[0]` works, but I'll make some research.

Comment: If you are not familiar with lambdas, now might be a good time to look up on them; although the hist function would just as well be written as a regular python function. The point of this wrapper function is to adapt the function  signature of np.histogram (3 or more inputs)->(two outputs) to the signature apply_along_axis expects. All but one argument to np.histogram should be constant, and we don't really care about the second return value.

Comment: Ive edited the code such that the bin boundaries returned by np.histogram are also stored; this might make it more clear what is going on

Comment: In this example, how could I get the intervals? I guess that the lambda selects just the first return, but I have to know the intervals to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: beat you to it by 9 seconds :)

Comment: xD One last question. I have a book here about Python, but it is too simple. Do you have any good book to recommend? Thank you. (:

Comment: Also, note that you can also explicitly specify the binning boundaries, rather than just a regularly spaced number of bins. This would also absolves you of having to capture this output.

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know of any books. But for this type of work, numpy is really your friend, and id say it makes more sense to learn it concurrently with python, rather than trying to learn plain python first. There is quite some good tutorial material on numpy online.

Comment: Yeah, this is how I'm doing so far. I couldn't apply you example to my program, trying to discover what I did wrong.

Comment: I know that I have to pass an ndarray. But I have to use my class. How can I achieve this? I've tried this: np.array(realizations). But it didn't work.

Comment: This method presented here only works on actual 3d arrays; not on something that's kinda like a 3d array. On a fundamental level, often you don't need an imagedata class at all. Can it do anything that a 2d python array cant? A more functional/vectorized style is often much nicer than classic OOP for these type of problems. If you insist on your imagedata class though, its better to have a single 3d array with contiguous layout that owns the data, and pass the imagedata classes merely a view to their respective slices.

Comment: but as for a minimally invasive method to get your current setup to play nicely with numpy; voxeldata = np.array([image.data for image in realizations]) should do the trick. This should copy your triply-nested list into a 3d array suitable for use with numpy. But again, the real question is, why your data isn't in that 3d array in the first place, because I doubt this will be the first or last time you will want to do any kind of efficient processing on it.

Comment: note that np.array(realizations) does not work because Imagedata does not expose the ndarray interface. You could make ImageData inherit from ndarray though; if you would restructure your code along those lines, it would work.

Comment: If you third axis is very dynamic, it may indeed be better to keep the data as a list of 2d arrays. The cost of converting that to a 3d array when needed is also insignificant compared to the very high cost of converting your triple-nested list. The latter requires the unboxing of all x*y*z python objects, whereas the former is mostly just a memcopy of a few pieces of contiguous memory.

Comment: Yes, the 3rd dimension is unknown (depends of the user option). But do you think if I start my data as `self.data = np.arange(width*height).reshape(height, width)` I can get some benefit? Really, really thanks for your attention.

Comment: Even doing this `data = np.array([image.data for image in realizations])
        # Apply this for each pixel
        hist_data = np.apply_along_axis(hist, 0, data)` it didn't work.

Comment: if by 'some', you mean 'a few orders of magnitude', then yes ;). how did that code fail exactly?

Comment: I print that the data type is numpy array and even so it doesn't work at all. It must be something stupid that I'm doing.

Comment: Works as expected for me. That said, the arange initialization gives a somewhat funny histogram. Are you using the latest numpy?

Comment: No, I'm using Numpy 1.7.1. I'm stuck at this problem since 01/07. Rs. Dying here.

Comment: latest is 1.8, but I doubt that's the problem. cant hurt to upgrade though. Did you actually propagate my 'return h' edit to the code you are running? If that error is still relevant, it does not sound like it

Comment: Holy crap! I saw your edit, but not this line in specific. It worked! xDDD Thank you a LOT!

Answer (score 1):

Parallelization certainly would not be my first port of call in optimizing this kind of thing. Your main problem is that you're doing lots of looping at the Python level. Python is inherently slow at this kind of thing. 
One option would be to learn how to write Cython extensions and write the histogram bit in Cython. This might take you a while.
Actually, taking a histogram of pixel values is a very common task in computer vision and it has already been efficiently implemented in OpenCV (which has python wrappers). There are also several functions for taking histograms in the numpy python package (though they are slower than the OpenCV implementations).